# EAS ignoring local versionCode in build

Tags: android, react-native, expo, version, eas

I recently updated our Expo project from sdk 44 to 46.
During that process, I switched from `Expo build:android` to `eas build -p android`.

Everything is running as expected, except the version code is not compiled into the aab/apk files correctly, so I cant push updates to google play.

The version code is already set to 26, as we did release previous versions, and the semVer is 1.1.1 currently. EAS also doesn't show the correct version codes in the dashboard.
I tried setting `"appVersionSource": "local"` as well as `"remote"`, but neither works. (As far as I understand, local should be the correct parameter.

`eas build` generally seems to ignore other parameters from the app.config.js, like the splash images, app icons and background colors (I didn't include those lines in the code examples below to keep it short)

### eas.json

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 2.3.0",
    "appVersionSource": "local"
  },
  "build": {
    ...
    "production": {
      "channel": "production",
      "env": {
        "APP_ENV": "production"
      },
      "android": {
        "buildType": "app-bundle",
        "image": "latest"
      }
    }
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

### app.config.js

```
import 'dotenv/config';
    
module.exports = {
  expo: {
    name: '...',
    slug: '...',
    version: '1.1.1',
    assetBundlePatterns: ['**/*'],
    android: {
      package: '...',
      versionCode: 26,
      softwareKeyboardLayoutMode: 'pan',
    },
    extra: {
      eas: {
        projectId: '...',
      },
      releaseChannel: process.env.APP_ENV,
    },
  },
};
```

#### Eas showing the wrong version nr

[image: Eas shows the wrong version nr]

Comment: do you have other config other than `app.config.js`? like `app.json`?

Comment: The problem was, that i ran `expo prebuild` during the move to 46. This ejected the app and in bare workflow those config files are ignored

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running `npx expo prebuild` or `npx expo run:android` That would generate the native Android project, which is basically like the Bare workflow.

See the following post for some more details and what you can do:
https://forums.expo.dev/t/should-i-exclude-ios/63094/4

Comment: Thanks Stefan, this was actually it! It took me a long time of searching through the eas documentation to find this information. I ran `expo prebuild` to check some configurations i made, as it was recommended elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

In my case [sdk 47, eas-cli/3.9.2, darwin-x64, node-v19.6.1], with `"appVersionSource": "remote"` in `eas.json` file, changing the `runtimeVersion: { policy: 'appVersion' }` in `app.config.ts` file was helpful.

More read on `runtimeVersion` in [expo documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/eas-update/runtime-versions).